# linux loop over the text files inside of one level subfolders

Tags: bash, loops, directory

I have a structure like this:

```
2020/    
   file1.txt
   file2.txt
2021/
   file4.txt
   file5.txt
```

...etc

I would like to create a bash script to loop over the text files to read them line by line and parse them

I am starting to learn bash and after several stack overflow questions read I thought the following would work:

```
for file in /{2020..2022}/*.txt;
    do
        echo $file
    done
```

this bash script is saved in the folder containing 2020, 2021, and 2022 and run from there.

my explanation:
the curly brackets would expand to 2020, 2021, 2022 and then under that level all the files with extension .txt would be given.
bu it does not work.

why?

Comment: Path in `for` starts with `/` so it is absolute.

Comment: @JFerro, remove the leading `/`

Comment: or prefix it with a dot `.`

Comment: You can find out such things easily by yourself by running the program with `set -x` turned on.

Comment: Try if `echo /{2020..2022}/*.txt` prints what you expect. I bet it doesn’t, due to the extra leading slash.